# Concatenating date field with char value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, concatenation

Not sure, but I feel I am missing something very stupid for which I am not getting desired result.

Query is pretty simple

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN 
GROUPING(DATEPART(YEAR,[ENTRY DATE]))=1 THEN 'GRAND TOTAL'
WHEN 
GROUPING(DATEPART(MONTH,[ENTRY DATE]))=1 THEN 'YEAR TOTAL'
WHEN 
GROUPING([ENTRY DATE])=1 
THEN 
CONVERT(CHAR(4), [ENTRY DATE], 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), [ENTRY DATE], 120) 
ELSE
CONVERT(VARCHAR,[ENTRY DATE])
END AS [ENTRY DATE],
COUNT([WORKTYPE]) AS [TOTAL VOLUME]
 FROM Assessment.INDIVIDUAL_MAIN
 WHERE [WorkType] IN ('QUERY','ASSESSMENT','DECLINE TO BRANCH')
GROUP BY ROLLUP(DATEPART(YEAR,[ENTRY DATE]),DATEPART(MONTH,[ENTRY DATE]),[ENTRY DATE])
```

So instead of getting YEAR AND MONTH Concat, I am getting null

```
+-------------+-------+
| 2014-06-27  | 10757 |
+-------------+-------+
| 2014-06-28  |     2 |
| 2014-06-29  |     5 |
| 2014-06-30  |    16 |
| NULL        | 10780 |
| 2014-07-27  |     1 |
| NULL        |     1 |
| YEAR TOTAL  | 10781 |
| 2015-06-27  |     1 |
| NULL        |     1 |
| YEAR TOTAL  |     1 |
| GRAND TOTAL | 10782 |
+-------------+-------+
```

When I simply write 'Year' or 'Grand Total', its working well but I would like to show the Month and Year value rather than names.

What is that I am doing wrong? Any insight would be of great help.

**Edit 1**: this is my expected result

```
+-------------+-------+
| 2014-06-27  | 10757 |
+-------------+-------+
| 2014-06-28  |     2 |
| 2014-06-29  |     5 |
| 2014-06-30  |    16 |
| 2014-06     | 10780 |
| 2014-07-27  |     1 |
| 2014-07     |     1 |
| 2014        | 10781 |
| 2015-06-27  |     1 |
| 2015-06     |     1 |
| 2015        |     1 |
| GRAND TOTAL | 10782 |
+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: So where you have null/10780, you want Jun 2014/10780?

Comment: @Andrew Nope I want `2014-06` (to show this is the rollup total for june 2014) and then `2014-07`..so on a forth...similarly for the year field I want `2014`, `2015` etc etc...

Comment: I'd suggest simplifying.  What does `select distinct CONVERT(CHAR(4), [ENTRY DATE], 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), [ENTRY DATE], 120)  FROM Assessment.INDIVIDUAL_MAIN
 WHERE [WorkType] IN ('QUERY','ASSESSMENT','DECLINE TO BRANCH')` result in?

Comment: @Andrew it results as expected July 2014 etc etc...but when I use the same with the query above it results in null..not sure what is happening

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think you want this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN GROUPING(DATEPART(YEAR,[ENTRY DATE]))=1 
      THEN  DATENAME(yyyy,[ENTRY DATE])
    WHEN GROUPING(DATEPART(MONTH,[ENTRY DATE]))=1 
      THEN DATENAME(yyyy,[ENTRY DATE])+' - '+DATENAME(mm,[ENTRY_DATE])
    WHEN GROUPING([ENTRY DATE])=1 
      THEN CAST([ENTRY DATE] AS VARCHAR(50))
    ELSE 'GRAND TOTAL'
  END AS [ENTRY DATE],
  COUNT([WORKTYPE]) AS [TOTAL VOLUME]
FROM Assessment.INDIVIDUAL_MAIN
WHERE [WorkType] IN ('QUERY','ASSESSMENT','DECLINE TO BRANCH')
GROUP BY ROLLUP(DATEPART(YEAR,[ENTRY DATE]),DATEPART(MONTH,[ENTRY DATE]),[ENTRY DATE])
```

Comment: I want `Concatenated Year and Month` field, after extracting the year and date part from my date field, what I am getting is null, I am not looking to replace null with `''`

Comment: @YVXS - it is totally unclear what the problem is to me.

Comment: I have added expected result, are you able to get it now?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ROLLUP` inserts null into the `[ENTRY DATE]` column in the summary rows.  That's why "YEAR" and "GRANT" work, but anything that references `[ENTRY DATE]` is null.  The non-summary rows (where `GROUPING(x) = 0`) *are* able to show `[ENTRY DATE]`.

I'm not sure it's possible to get the results you want with `ROLLUP`.  You may need to go about it a different way.

Here's a possible solution.  It computes the various aggregates and then unions the results together.  It's kind of messy, but...it works (I think).

```
--Daily
select CONVERT(varchar, [Entry Date]) [ENTRY DATE], 
COUNT(WORKTYPE) COUNT, 
CONVERT(varchar, [Entry Date]) sort
from Assessment.INDIVIDUAL_MAIN
group by [ENTRY DATE]

union

--Monthly
select convert(varchar, DATEPART(year, [Entry Date])) + '-' + convert(varchar, DATEPART(month, [Entry Date])), 
COUNT(WORKTYPE), 
convert(varchar, DATEPART(year, [Entry Date])) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MONTH([ENTRY DATE])), 2) + '-40'
from Assessment.INDIVIDUAL_MAIN
group by DATEPART(year, [Entry Date]), DATEPART(month, [Entry Date])

union

--Yearly
select convert(varchar, DATEPART(year, [Entry Date])), 
COUNT(WORKTYPE), 
convert(varchar, DATEPART(year, [Entry Date])) + '-20-40'
from Assessment.INDIVIDUAL_MAIN
group by DATEPART(year, [Entry Date])

union

--Grand Total
select 'GRAND TOTAL', 
count(WorkType), 
'9999'
from Assessment.INDIVIDUAL_MAIN
order by sort
```

Comment: yep...took some time for me to realize that but the problem (or rather the reality) was the summed up filed (sub total and grand total) being blank and not the [entry date]...

Comment: @YVXS, I added a possible solution to my answer.